# Accessing Methods from a superInterface Using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, superclass

I need to get the methods defined in the super Interfaces using reflection since reflection does not provide the methods from super interface using currentClass.getDeclaredMethods().
So, is it possible to get the super Interface methods?

```
  // I am using the Jms interface TopicConnection. But I am not able to access the "setClientID" method using reflection.
        // That method is present in the super Interface "Connection". How do I get to that?
        Class<?> superClass = topicConnectionClass.getSuperclass(); // this does not give the superInterface for the current Interface. and gives null since for interface superClass is null
        checkMethod = superClass.getDeclaredMethod("setClientID", String.class);
```

Comment: A short example of what you're trying to achieve would be helpful.

Comment: I have placed the small code snippet

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getInterfaces()` instead of `getSuperclass()`.

However - there must be a class that defines `setClientID`, it must be one of the super classes, so it would be also appropriate to iterate along the super class relation.